# How to convert .pkl file into .csv or read .pkl into R as dataframe

Tags: python, r, csv, export-to-csv, pickle

I've never used python and I've received some .pkl files which have some tracking data and in the data set are a training set with 7500 sequences and two separate set of sequences for testing the format of each sequence is as follows:
- Each sequence is a matrix (numpy 2D array) with 46 columns. Each row contains 23 pairs of (x,y) coordinates...and so on.

I've tried to use the reticulate package and then for example having the file in my working directory running this code hasn't worked and I don't know what else to do...

```
> data_1 = py_load_object(test_data_1.pkl, pickle = "pickle")
Error in py_resolve_dots(list(...)) : object 'test_data_1.pkl' not     found
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably pretty close. I am not familiar with `reticulate` but if the files you have were serialized with the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, you should be able to de-serialize with the same module.

```
import pickle

with open('test_data_1.pkl','rb') as f:
    data_1 = pickle.load(f)
```

You must give `pickle.load()` a file handle using the built-in `open`. If you don't want to keep all the pickle files in the same working folder as your script, you can use an absolute or relative path given as a string. There are more details about `open` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You can also use `pathlib.Path` objects for the filepath if you want to get fancier.

Comment: and that's python code I need to run right? Would it work on something like pycharm?

Comment: Yup, the posted code will load a file `test_data_1.pkl` in the same working folder as your python script into the variable `data_1`. It will certainly run in pycharm or any other python IDE but you will need to ensure that the pickle file is indeed where you are saying it is. If you are getting a `FileNoteFoundError`, consider using an absolute path. For example, if you put the file in your C:\ drive, you can give the path as `'C:\test_data_1.pkl'`.